# Arduino - M-Duino 21 Interrupt Pin

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Hi I am using Industrial Shield M-duino 21 and i want to use Interrupt Pin I0_5.  I read their docs and the find the code to use it but I am getting **I0_5 was not declared in this scope error**. As far as i know everything looks to be declared. I need a second set of eyes on this code, Please help. Following is the code.

```
  #define INTERRUPT I0_5 //other pins: I0_6, I2_6, I2_5, I1_6, I1_5 (M-Duino) I0_0, I0_3, I0_2, I0_1 (Ardbox)

volatile bool state = false;

void setup() {
  pinMode(INTERRUPT, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(INTERRUPT), function_call_back, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  if (state == true){
    Serial.println("Interrupt activated");
    state = false;
  }
}

void function_call_back(){ //Change led state
  state = true;
}
```

Comment: @Juraj Yes it does.

Comment: @Juraj Yes, I included http://apps.industrialshields.com/main/arduino/boards/package_industrialshields_index.json the path in File/Preferences/

Comment: @Juraj Yes, I have different codes working on board without any problems. Problem is only when use Interrupt pins

Comment: the `I0_5` constant is not special for interrupts. it is a way industrialshields have IO pins labeled.

Comment: @Juraj They say to use these pins in a different way as these are interrupts pins. See here https://www.industrialshields.com/technical-features-industrial-m-duino-plc-arduino-ethernet-21-ios-analog-digital-plus-wifi

Comment: the different way is that digitalPinToInterrupt must be used to map the io pin number to interrupt number. your board is basically Arduino Mega. they even map the pins to Mega pin numbers first so I0_5 is pin 2 and it is mapped to external interrupt 0.